# How to not .append div on desktop window resize

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

If the window screen size is more then 768px - div `<tab-content>` should not be appending to `<li>` (BTW. it works if the window is made smaller from the desktop size but if you start from the smaller window size and drag to the bigger desktop size it should not append the div at all) -

**[See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/719wcttm/4/)**

html -

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

             <div role="tabpanel" id="tabs-test">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#divTab1" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab2" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab3" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab4" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content-outer">
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="divTab1">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab3">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab4">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabpanel -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

js -

```
    //NEW Tabs to Accordion
window.tabsAreEnabled = false;

var enableTabs = function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        // Initial move to first active li
        $('.tab-content').appendTo(".nav-tabs li.active").hide();

        $(".nav-tabs").on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function () {
            $('.tab-content').appendTo($(this));
            $('.tab-content').show();
        });
        $(".nav-tabs").on('click', 'li.active', function () {
            $('.tab-content').toggle();
        });
        window.tabsAreEnabled = true;
    } else {
        $(".tab-content").appendTo(".tab-content-outer");
        window.tabsAreEnabled = false;
    }
};

enableTabs();

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (!window.tabsAreEnabled) {
        enableTabs();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you actually want, but I gonna give a shot.

[Take a look [updated update of update]](https://jsfiddle.net/719wcttm/17/)

```
var isActive = false;
var $tabContent = $('.tab-content');
var $navTabs = $('.nav-tabs');

var enableTabs = function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        // Initial move to first active li
        $tabContent.appendTo(".nav-tabs li.active");

        $navTabs.on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function () {
            if(!isActive)
                return;
            $tabContent.appendTo($(this));
            $tabContent.show();
        });
        $navTabs.on('click', 'li.active', function () {
            if(!isActive)
                return;
            $tabContent.toggle();
        });
        isActive = true;
    } else {
        $tabContent.appendTo(".tab-content-outer");
        isActive = false;
    }
};

enableTabs();

if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $tabContent.hide();
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    enableTabs();
});
```

Comment: I am appending the content to each list item that has a class of active. All works well except the .append() should not be firing if viewed at more then 769px.

Comment: 2nd shot, take a look at it @user1004158

Comment: One bug that is still there is, if a tab is showing it's content on desktop, it no longer shows its content, when dragged at the smaller accordion size.

Comment: @user1004158 Piece of cake, remove the hidden/show, now it should work perfectly

Comment: on page load all tabs should be collapsed if less then 768px.

Comment: there u go, page load hidden if <768px

Comment: But now back to square 1 regarding resize from small to large (ie. the tab content is being hidden at desktop size)